# $SKIP stage contain all previous records

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of `1.2M` documents and I am making a list of them using `pagination` (25 per page). For that, I am using `Aggregation Framework` with `$sort->$skip->$limit->$project` stages respectively. Things are working fine but a wierd behaviour of `$skip` causing `nReturned` docs a high value as i keep exploring pages.

For example, assume `$limit => 25`, Page 1 => `nReturned 25, Skip 0, Display 1-25`, on Page 2 => `nReturned 50, Skip 25, Display 26-50` , on Page 3 => `nReturned 75, Skip 50, Display 51-75` and so on... and on Page LAST => `nReturned SOME_MILLION, Skip MILLION, Display LAST_MILLIONS`

If, I visit last pages, `nReturned, totalDocsExamined and totalKeysExamined` will be near to 1.2M as i have a lot of record.

**Query**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $sort : {
        date_added : -1
    }
},
{
    $skip : 50  
},
{
    $limit : 25
},
{
    $project : {
        luid : 1,
        name : 1
    }
}
])
```

Am i doing something wrong or is there any way to optimise this query?

Comment: I forgot to mention that i am using Index on `date_added : -1`

Answer (score 1):

Using `$skip` is very memory inefficient, imaging if you are going to the last page, you will be skipping 1.2M records.

Will you really be displaying page 10000 under your pagination or will there be `<` and `>` arrows?

A better way would be using the last key, for example records of the following.

```
{ 
   _id: 1
   _data: ...
},
{   
   _id: 2
   data: ...
}....
```

At the first page, my last key will be 25, second page, my last key will be 50, or maybe e.g. 62, if my keys are not in order (deleted in between).

My pagination will then be as simple as

```
Model.find({ _id: { $gt: last }}).limit(25).sort({ _id: 1 })
```

Where `last` is the last id retrieved in page 1.

calling for the *previous page* is as simple as switching `$gt` to `$lt` and reverse the sorting

Tip: in most cases nobody will go select page e.g 100204, we will usually have a search function if we do have this many records.

**If we really need to use `$skip`**, a caching layer should be in order to cache the records retrieved (e.g. using redis) to prevent repeatedly calling the same query.

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggestion. I've already implemented SEARCH function and normally ppl use that only.

Comment: As you suggested `Redis`, MongoDB is `NoSQL` as well as Redis too. Is there any benefit to use Redis for All Read Operations as a layer on top of Mongo?

Comment: Redis acts only as a caching layer to store the results of your queries. So your algorithm is something like `if (!redisCache) model.find(...)`. You can set redis to expire the key after a certain time (e.g. 60 seconds), so within that 60 seconds, your mongodb query is called only once, resulting in faster response, especially for query that takes long time to execute.

Comment: Imagine if you have a search + autocomplete feature, searching for the word "algorithm" will call mongodb **9 times**. If 10 people search for the same word within short period of time, you will be redundently calling the same heavy query 90 times. While if you add a caching layer, redis can response to the request in a shorter response time.